# Get Password using CLI from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I stored password in azure key vault account and i want that to be get from cli so that I can copy them any time when ever needed

much appreciated for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is the command for displaying password through CLI*

```
az keyvault secret show \
    --name <Your Secret Name> \
    --vault-name <Your Key Vault Name> \
    --query value \
    --output tsv
```

*I have tested in my local environment, and it worked for me*

[image]